# Escape quotes in attribute values with Java

Tags: java, html, xml, escaping

I have an arbitrary large HTML string with incorrectly escaped attribute values. I would like to get the full HTML string with properly escaped attribute values. I would like to do this in Java.

For example, given this incorrectly escaped HTML tag:

```
<p name="Chalupa "Batman" McArthur">Chalupa "Batman" McArthur</p>
```

I want this output:

```
<p name="Chalupa &quot;Batman&quot; McArthur">Chalupa "Batman" McArthur</p>
```

StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml() or replaceAll() replaces all invalid HTML characters like this:

```
&lt;p name=&quot;Chalupa &quot;Batman&quot; McArthur&quot;&gt;Chalupa &quot;Batman&quot; McArthur&lt;/p&gt;
```

I want the characters within attribute values escaped properly, but the rest of the HTML left alone so it can properly be processed by a browser. Is there a java library that can handle this issue?

Comment: Try using the String Tokenizer to get the string between 'Name=' and '>' and then pass that String alone to format the spacial characters

Comment: This isn't quite a well-specified question. For instance, what do you want your code to do in the following cases?
    `<p name="one"two" />`
    `<p key="three" value="twelve" />`
    `<p name = "badly "formatted=" text" />`

You're trying to fix ambiguous HTML as a post-processing step. If you have any control over the process that creates this HTML, you should fix it there. But, maybe you're trying to fix a problem handed you by the internet. In which case, (a) you have my sympathies, and (b) exactly what behavior do you want?